# How Can I Set CategoryIds for a product?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

I have a product and I want to set some attributes to it before saving.
So I have:

```
$newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$newProduct->setName($model->getDescription())
                            ->setName("aaaaa")
                            ->setCategoryIds(array(2));

$newProduct->save();
```

It saves the `Name` attribute, but `CategoryIds` doesn't get saved. Any ideas why?
I also tried:

```
                           ->setData('category_ids',2)
```

Comment: it seams you are doing it right. did you try with other values instead of 2? Also, are you sure that the category with the id 2 exists?

Comment: I've tried with more values. Most of them I take from `product save form` ( so I think can't be wrong). I don't know where it is suposed to be saved that `category_ids`.

Comment: you can start debugging in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product::_saveCategories`

Comment: I've tried this, and also debuging on `save()` for products. Excepting the fact that `CategoryIds()` is empty, it works fine.